# How to use HTTP Live Streaming's EXT-X-MEDIA?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm currently working on a project that has been filmed several times during the year, at different seasons.

The different video tracks are time synced, so I'd like to take advantage of HTTP Live Streaming's **[EXT-X-MEDIA](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-07#section-3.3.9)** to let the users switch between seasons on iOS-devices.

I've setup an M3U8 playlist containing the video, but I can't seem to expose the *controls* in the Quicktime player – neither on the iPhone nor the iPad.

Here's my playlist:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID="500kbs",NAME="Winter",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID="500kbs",NAME="Spring",AUTOSELECT=NO,DEFAULT=NO,URI="spring.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID="500kbs",NAME="Summer",AUTOSELECT=NO,DEFAULT=NO,URI="summer.m3u8"

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="aac",LANGUAGE="eng",NAME="English",AUTOSELECT=YES, \
DEFAULT=YES,URI="audio.m3u8"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=754857,VIDEO="500kbs",AUDIO="aac",CODECS="avc1.42e01e,mp4a.40.2"
./winter.m3u8
```

Shouldn't this work?

Answer (score 2):

The GROUP-ID is for multiple language support. It's of course possible to shoe-horn in a new meaning, but I wouldn't expect very good client support.

But the playlist you provided isn't legal according to the latest spec.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-10#section-3.4.9.1

> All members of a group whose AUTOSELECT attribute has a value of YES MUST have LANGUAGE [RFC5646] attributes with unique values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, vipw. I've added a unique LANGUAGE attribute to the members of the video group, but it still didn't expose any new controls. I've simply used the example from an [Apple Technical Note](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2288/_index.html), which included the GROUP-ID. Is that wrong?

Comment: @HenrikLied Have you ever seen an example that allows choosing between video renditions? I've only ever seen it used for audio. Maybe the players just haven't implemented the functionality for switching the video.

Comment: I haven't seen either, @vipw – only read the tech note from Apple stating that it should be possible. Although, I do agree that they don't give too much info on how it'll be exposed in the UI. Do you have an example where audio switching has been implemented?

Comment: @HenrikLied Sorry, but I don't have a public example.

Comment: @HenrikLied https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/resources/http-streaming/examples/bipbop_16x9/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8

Comment: latest spec : https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8216#section-4.3.4.1.1